# Various space between Flex Item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to put various space between Logo and Menu in the Header, using `display:flex` then `justify-content: flex-end` to Menu and `flex-start` to Logo but it doesn't works.

I use `display: flex` and `align-items:center` on the header to have all the element on the header aligned. But now i have to place the menu at the end and the Logo at the start.

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
}

header {
 height: auto;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul.BarMenu {
 background:#fff;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: flex;
}

nav ul.BarMenu a{
 margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
 color: black;
 font-size: 13px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(119, 87, 247, 0);
}

nav ul a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(119, 87, 247, 1);
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header" role="banner">
            <div class="logo-holder">
                <a href="#"><h1 class="logo">LOGO</h1></a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="BarMenu">
                    <a href="#"><li>text</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>text</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li></li>text</a>
                    <a href="#"><li>text</li></a>
                    <a href="#" class="Start"><li>text</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `justify-content: space-between;` to the header.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul.BarMenu {
  background: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul.BarMenu a {
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
  color: black;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(119, 87, 247, 0);
}

nav ul a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(119, 87, 247, 1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header" role="banner">
    <div class="logo-holder">
      <a href="#">
        <h1 class="logo">LOGO</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="BarMenu">
        <a href="#">
          <li>text</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>text</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li></li>text</a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>text</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="Start">
          <li>text</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: we say `un problème` not `une probleme` ;)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to write so:

```
header {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: space-between;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Khalil Karim: Hope It helps!

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
}

header {
    /* height: auto; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul.BarMenu {
 background:#fff;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: flex;
}

nav ul.BarMenu a{
    display: flex;
    /* margin: 0 1em 0 1em; */
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(119, 87, 247, 0);
    padding: 0 20px;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(119, 87, 247, 1);
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header" role="banner">
            <div class="logo-holder">
                <a href="#"><h1 class="logo">LOGO</h1></a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="BarMenu">
                    <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>About Us</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li></li>Services</a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Blog</li></a>
                    <a href="#" class="Start"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```